# In Win 10, how do I move a folder to onedrive?

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, onedrive

I have a new Windows 10 computer. I want to move my documents folder to one drive. how do I do this? Once a file is in Onedrive, can I access it without having internet access?

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the location of your **Documents** to **OneDrive**, then configure some **OneDrive settings**.

### To redirect a folder to a new location

1. Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd> and type `documents`
2. Right click on the Documents folder on the left side pane, click **Properties**
3. Click the **Location** tab, then change the location to the current location of your **OneDrive** folder (right click on OneDrive and click properties to see it's current location)

[image]

### Making your OneDrive files offline

1. **Right click** on OneDrive in the Taskbar
2. Go to **Settings**
3. Select, "Make all files available (offline)"

[image]